# Using strings to set folder path VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have been asked by my colleagues to write a program that allows us to enter a job number and it will take us to the proper folder within our database (SolidWorks EPDM).  The structure of the folders is as follows:  C:\Litania EPDM\Orders\XXXX\XX\number with the first set of Xs representing the year and the second set the month.  Example job number being 112113-444121-1X, so that 11 would be the month, 12 the day, 13 the year (2013), the middle six are the unique job number and the 1X is just a suffix which changed to 2X and so on if there are multiple orders under the same number.

What I need to accomplish is setting up variables (strings) that can hold the year with a "20" in front of it, the month, the number and the suffix then I need to combine those into a folder path.  Here is what I have:

```
Public Class ProjectLookup

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim day As String = CStr(DateText.Text)
        Dim string1 As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(day, 4)
        Dim month As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(string1, 2)
        Dim year As String = "20" + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(string1, 2)
        Dim num As String = CStr(NumberText.Text)
        Dim suff As String = CStr(SuffixText.Text)

        Process.Start("explorer.exe", "C:\Litania EPDM\Orders\" + year + " \ " + month + " \ " + num + suff)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Currently it runs and opens windows explorer, but does not go to the intended path.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us where it is taking you hence give us an idea of what is being generated incorrectly?  At a glance this all looks fine

Comment: Note that the `CStr()`s are pointless - `.Text` is already a string. You're also using _very_ old syntax - it's VB6-esque. instead of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(string1, 2)` do `string1.Left(2)`

Comment: Try to assign the path to a string variable first and check its contents to see if the path is correct. In one of my apps I open the path in explorer by simply using `Process.Start(StringVariableWithPathInIt)`

Answer (score 3):

The integrity of your code is wrong since you are concatenating strings with the "+" character, using VB6 methods (programming techniques of a decade ago), casting strings when is not needed (string properties), etc...

Also, an argument should be enclosed with double quotes to avoid problems, for example, in this case, a directory that contains spaces which is taken as more than 1 argument 'cause is not enclosed, then you just need to enclose it and it should work:

```
Process.Start("Explorer.exe", String.Format("""C:\Litania EPDM\Orders\{0}\{1}\{2}""", 
                                            year, month, num & suff ))
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have taken your suggestions and will try tomorrow at work.

Also, does it matter that the desired path (Litania EPDM) is a password protected vault?  All users are automatically logged into the vault when they log in to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to concatenate the file path like this:

```
Dim _path As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Litania EPDM\Orders", year, month, num & stuff)
If IO.File.Exists(_path) Then
 'proceed
End If
```

Comment: `Path.Combine` with up to four components was only introduced in .NET 4.0, in case anyone wants to try that with, say .NET 3.5.